# How to make getDerivedStateFromProps using useEffect in FC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an old React component (which is class), and now i'm trying to rewrite it to FC.
There are some class methods like constructor, componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount etc.
I faced some difficulties trying to rewrite method getDerivedStateFromProps. Here how it looks like:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: CourseProps, state: State): State | null {
    const {
        courseId,
    slideInfo,
    units,
    enterToCourse,
    courseInfo
    } = props;

    if (!units) {
        return null;
    }

    const slideId = slideInfo.slideId;

    if (state.currentCourseId !== courseId ||
    state.currentSlideId !== slideId ||
    slideInfo.slideType !== state.currentSlideType) {
    enterToCourse(courseId);
    const openUnitId = findUnitIdBySlideId(slideId, courseInfo);
    const openedUnit = openUnitId ? units[openUnitId] : undefined;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    const Page = WebEditor2.getOpenedPage(props.courseInfo, slideInfo?.slideType);
    const title = WebEditor2.getTitle(slideInfo.navigationInfo?.current.title);

    return {
        Page,
        title,
        currentSlideId: slideId,
        currentCourseId: courseId,
        currentSlideType: slideInfo.slideType,
        highlightedUnit: openUnitId || null,
        openedUnit,
    };
    }

    return null;
}
```

I made something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { courseId, slideInfo, units, enterToCourse, courseInfo } = props;

    if (!units) {
        return;
    }

    const slideId = slideInfo.slideId;

    if (state.currentCourseId !== courseId ||
        state.currentSlideId !== slideId ||
        slideInfo.slideType !== state.currentSlideType) {
        enterToCourse(courseId);
        const openUnitId = findUnitIdBySlideId(slideId, courseInfo);
        const openedUnit = openUnitId ? units[openUnitId] : undefined;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        const Page = getOpenedPage(props.courseInfo, slideInfo?.slideType);
        const title = getTitle(slideInfo.navigationInfo?.current.title);

    setState( {
        Page,
        title,
        currentSlideId: slideId,
        currentCourseId: courseId,
        currentSlideType: slideInfo.slideType,
        highlightedUnit: openUnitId || null,
        openedUnit,
    });
    }
}, [props.courseId, props.slideInfo, props.units, props.enterToCourse, props.courseInfo]);
```

But now i always have an error: *Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

How should i rewrite this method? Any help appreciated.

Comment: maybe change the dependencies in useEffect from props' properties to just props? so the setState only runs once when props change instead

Comment: There has been almost no reason at all, ever, to use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method. What is going on around this code in the class component that may better help inform of the function component equivalent? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, including the parent or wrapper component/container providing the props?